# actionscript 3.0 how to clear RAM

Tags: memory, actionscript, ram

i'm using actionscript p2p application to transfer files between peers. 
all received files byteArrays are stored in one array like this one:

```
recvFiles[peerID][fileID].data:ByteArray = FileReference.data
```

now i'm stuck in a such situation - what if someone decided to transfer files with a size greater than 1gb. this means that receiver memory is gonna be clogged.

how can i delete saved file byteArray after user save it on pc?

i thought about this:

```
recvFiles[peerID][fileID] = null;
```

but i'm a newbie in actionscript and i don't how it interracts with memory...

so my question is what is the best way to clear memory?

thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should do it. You can also try to force garbage collection immediately, although it is not officially supported. You can do this by making a LocalConnection. There is more about it here on Grant Skinner's blog:

http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/08/as3_resource_ma_2.html

```
try { 
   new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
   new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
} catch (e:*) {}
// the GC will perform a full mark/sweep on the second call.
```

If you are testing using the debug version of Flash Player 10 or greater, you can also force it:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#gc()

```
System.gc();
```

...but keep in mind that this 2nd option is only for the debug version. Most users won't have this installed.